# Self-host WebForms project using Visual Studio Community for Mac

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm working on my first ever .NET project. I'm using Visual Studio Community for Mac and I'm required to use a WebForms project.

I created the project using VS, the basic template, but I have no idea how to run it locally to get it to load in a browser.

Apparently most of the WebServer solutions (like Kestrel) require a Windows environment with IIS.

What are my options on the Mac?

To be clear, I'm constrained to use .NET with WebForms, I can't go with MVC for this project.

Comment: This is for a school project? It will be far easier for a beginner to get a Windows VM set up and running and use Visual Studio on it than to figure out how to get Mono and Web Forms running on a Mac.

Comment: @mason This is not a school project. This is for work. I'm assisting a team with their UI needs and their project is .NET based. I honestly rather not get a VM to do this because I'll be doing React work, not .NET work. But I need to be able to run the application. Although now that I'm thinking about it, if I could setup the VM with a mapped folder to write the code on macOS and run it the code on Windows, that would be a reasonable compromise. Separately, I'm not using Mono. Just .NET Core and VS Community.

Comment: .NET Core doesn't do Web Forms. Web Forms only runs on the full .NET Framework